# Change file owner in Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I would like to change the file owner of a Node.js-written file. I think there is no way to set the owner directly during file write (or maybe there's a way not documented?). Is there a way to change the owner afterwards?

My Node.js app runs in a docker container under the root user. So all files written by Node.js are owned by root. I want to set the owner to www-data, for example. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chown_path_uid_gid_callback) module:

```
fs.chown(path, 1,1, console.log);
```

Though this presumes you know the uid and gid of www-data (user) and www-data (group).

Comment: And if you don't know the uid and gid you can get it by peeking at `/etc/passwd/` (linux) with a command like `cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data`.